# Facebook batch request on /me/photos does not schedule my posts

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I was using the facebook graph api without batch requests to schedule posts of pictures to my pages.

Now I am trying to work with batch requests but I have an issue, the photo are posted immediately, even if I set the parameters to delay it.

Example:

```
$args = array(
    'message' => $this->message,
);
$args['published'] = false;
$args['scheduled_publish_time'] = strtotime($this->programmed_dt);

$appsecretProof = hash_hmac('sha256', $facebookPage['access_token'], self::APP_SECRET);

$queries[] = array('method'         => 'POST',
    'relative_url'   => urlencode('/' . $facebookPage['id'] . '/photos?access_token=' . $facebookPage['access_token'] . '&appsecret_proof=' . $appsecretProof),
    'body'           => $args,
    'attached_files' => 'file1',
);
$params['file1'] = '@' . realpath('images/' . $timestamp . '.jpg');
$urlPost = '?batch=' . json_encode($queries) . '&access_token=' . self::ACCESS_TOKEN;

$res = $this->fb->api($urlPost, 'POST', $params);
```

I have a response with the post ID, but the photo post is not scheduled ... Do you see anything wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found:

published and scheduled_publish_time should be passed to the relative_url

```
$relativeUrl = '/' . $facebookPage['id'] . '/photos?published=' . (string) $args['published'];
$relativeUrl .= $args['published'] ? '' : '&scheduled_publish_time=' . $args['scheduled_publish_time'] . '&access_token=' . $facebookPage['access_token'] . '&appsecret_proof=' . $appsecretProof;
```